# How can I determine if ValueGeneratedNever() has been called on an entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have entities where I need to supply a PK value on creation.

This is set in the DB context with `entity.Property(e => e.ID).ValueGeneratedNever();`

How can I examine an object at runtime to see if this has been called so that I can supply a value?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.ID).ValueGeneratedNever();
    });
}
//...
if(xxxx)
{
   myEntity.ID = GetNextId();
}
```

Comment: maybe this help ``if(myEntity.ID==default)``

Comment: No, I have some entities with DB set PKs and some with application set.  I was hoping for a way to check.